# Claims Transformation with ADAL

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

Is there a way to do Claims Transformation with the ADAL .net library and using *UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication*?

I'm able to do it in the SecuityTokenValidated Event when using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler` defines the virtual function `CreateClaimsIdentity` that you can take control of.

You would need to provide a custom implementation of `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` and set `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions.TokenHandler` to the custom implementation.

Comment: Can you please help me? I am using a custom `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` and overriding `CreateClaimsIdentity` and in there I am returning my own `MyClaimsIdentity` which inherits `ClaimsIdentity` and adds some properties. When I run this locally it works just fine, and my Web API controllers see my custom identity object, however when I run it on Azure, they don't, they see the original `ClaimsIdentity` which the base token handler returned...